# How to use android.test.mock in Android Studio

Tags: android, unit-testing

I'm trying to use [MockContext](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/mock/MockContext.html) in unit tests for Android projects in Android Studio. The problem is, package `android.test.*` is not visible in the project.

I'm not sure what should I add to Gradle in order to import it. I tried `com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2` and `androidx.test:rules:1.1.1` (one of the suggestions made by IDE), but that's not the one I'm looking for.

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myApp"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Error message when compiling:

> error: package android.test.mock does not exist

**What should I add to gradle to have access to `android.test` packages?**

Comment: You used `implementation` for that dependency. Try `testImplementation`.

Comment: @CommonsWare That doesn't help, but thanks for catching that :) Edited.

Comment: Had the same problem here! Strangely, Siena's answer wasn't working for my **library module**'s test... and then adding  `useLibrary 'android.test.mock'` in my **application module**'s build.gradle FIXED the failing import!!!  In my **library module** test. Weird...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually, you can access `android.test.mock` from your unit tests and gain access to the `MockContext` class. For AndroidX projects, you can add the following in your app module's `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    ...
    useLibrary 'android.test.mock'
}
```

Source: https://developer.android.com/training/testing/set-up-project

Comment: [Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33014618/452775) of `useLibrary`: This directive adds the library to the classpath when building but does not add the library to the APK.

Comment: Not helpful as it dont work I add this line and still cannot access MockContext
also didnt find anything helpfull in documentation.

Answer (score 2):

That class is a framework class, not from a library. You can tell by the package name: anything in `android.` (instead of `com.android.` or `androidx.`) is a framework class. Hence, you could only use that for instrumented tests, not unit tests.

You can either create custom mocks (e.g., with Mockito) or use [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/), depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Ah, I see. I was hoping for an easy to use mock. But why does `android.content.Context` work in unit tests? It also seems to start with `android.` only.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: That depends on what you mean by "work". You won't be able to create or get a `Context` in a unit test, outside of mocks. But you do raise a good point: I am not certain why your `import` is not working.

Comment: Recent version of mockk framework fails when mocking android Context and I cant use robolectric

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer suggests to use `android.test.mock`. That can work, in the sense that you can run tests with it. However, it is a kind of overkill, as it means you will be doing instrumented test instead of unit tests. That brings with it all the implications and overhead, etc., of doing instrumented tests, whereas if you just need a context object for unit tests, it is not necessary nor advisable to use `android.test.mock`.

Furthermore, the question above actually is asking for some kind of Context object to use for unit tests. And Google's [developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests#java) does address this question, with sample code that imports `android.content.Context` and then mocks it with Mockito.

But isn't `android.content.Context` a framework class? Then how can it be used in unit tests rather than instrumented tests? As can be seen in [developer reference for android.content.Context](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context), it is an abstract class. Hence it is suitable for simple mocking with Mockito.